# Display Post author IP address in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to display the users post ip address in wordpress.
I have used `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` for this but the ip address for all is same.
Any query for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by saving user IP address in the post meta field.

> ```
>  $post_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
>
>  add_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_ip', $post_ip );
> ```